# Using Django .update() with .get()

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have an invoice table

```
# app/models.py

class tbl_invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_id                      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    invoice_number                  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quotation_id                    = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quotation_number                = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    invoiced                        = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

this table contains invoice and quotations records, system user has the option to convert any quotation to invoice, but the quotation record will still remain along with the newly generated invoice record

and this is my views

```
#views.py

    obj = tbl_invoice.objects.get(pk='someId')   # getting existing record with pk
    obj.pk = None
    obj.invoice_id  = 'someId'
    obj.quotation_id = None             
    obj.invoice_number = 'someValue'
    obj.quotation_number = None
    obj.invoiced = 'no'
    obj.type_status = 'invoice'
    obj.save()
```

above code is working fine, it creates a new invoice record and also maintains the old quotation record

however, after converting quotation to invoice I also want to update the `invoiced` value on the quotation record to **yes**

for that, I tried

```
obj.update(invoiced = 'yes')
```

but `.update()` doesn't work on `.get()`

how can I create a new record from an existing record and update the old record at the same time
or do I have to use multiple queries

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply,

```py
old_obj = tbl_invoice.objects.get(pk='someId')  # getting existing record with pk

# creating new object
new_obj = old_obj

# altering new object values
new_obj.pk = None
new_obj.invoice_id = 'someId'
new_obj.quotation_id = None
new_obj.invoice_number = 'someValue'
new_obj.quotation_number = None
new_obj.invoiced = 'no'
new_obj.type_status = 'invoice'

# altering old object value
old_obj.invoiced = "yes"

# saving objects
new_obj.save()
old_obj.save()
```

Comment: ah! simple yet effective, why couldn't I think of it...
anyways, thanks for the help :D